# Tuples and ValueTuples

Tags: .net, powershell

### Understanding how tuples works.

1. What's the point of the tuple? Give pls one-several examples where tuples are really useful and better than other array-like types.
2. Comparing

```
$t1 = [Tuple]::Create(4, 5)
$t2 = [Tuple]::Create(4, 5)
$t1 -eq $t2 #True (How??)
```

As i know, only this code can return "True":

```
$t1 = [ValueTuple]::Create(4, 5)
$t2 = [ValueTuple]::Create(4, 5)
$t1 -eq $t2 #True (This is correct)
```

That's the one of the differences between [Tuple] and [ValueTuple]. But...

3. For what there is a possibility of creating empty tuple? How we can use this?

```
$t = [ValueTuple]::Create()
$t|fl        # Length : 0
$t.GetType() # ValueTuple
```

$t haven't **.add()** method, or smth like this.

4. What is the syntax to create tuple in posh with named fields? Like(c#):

```cs
var tuple = (count: 5, sum: 10);
Console.WriteLine(tuple.count);
Console.WriteLine(tuple.GetType());
```

```
5
System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. To represent multiple values without having to declare an explicit type - especially useful inside methods (where an additional type would be pure overhead, and wouldn't add to expressivity); in the case of value-tuples, this is all done without any heap allocations (unlike arrays); also, arrays don't perform #2 below:
2. Tuples perform memberwise equality tests
3. (Edited) A zero-element value-tuple does exist (`ValueTuple.Create()`); this *may* be useful to create a nil value that implements `IStructuralComparable`, `IStructuralEquatable`, and `ITuple` - but this doesn't seem *hugely* useful, except to satisfy an API constraint
4. You've... shown the syntax; this relates to value-tuples, and the name data is specific to the call-site: it doesn't actually exist anywhere in the type system (although it is exposed outwards to callers via attributes, it is not exposed inwards to callees - which means names can't be used by things like serialization tools or ORMs); essentially, it is just the compiler / parser - not the runtime - that knows about the names

Comment: "No, a zero-element tuple does not exist" - What do you mean? $t in [3] exists of course.

Comment: @Danny huh you're right; ValueTuple.Create() does indeed exist as a zero-element tuple. Perhaps useful to create a void structural-comparable entry, but: kinda niche - not many *mainstream* uses for that; TIL; there is no zero-element Tuple.Create(), only ValueTuple.Create()

Answer (score 3):

**[Marc Gravell's helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66292589/45375) covers the C# / general .NET perspective; let me add a *PowerShell-specific* one**:

With respect to `System.Tuple<...>`, which are *reference types*:

> `$t1 -eq $t2 # True (How??)`

PowerShell's `-eq` operator does *not* act like C's `==`, which would test for *reference equality* here; put simply, PowerShell's `-eq`[ acts like `$t1.Equals($t2)`, which with `System.Tuple<...>` (as well as with *value type* `System.ValueTuple<...>`) performs *member-wise* equality comparison and reports `$true` if all members are equal.

> What is the syntax to create tuple in posh with named fields? Like(c#):

There is *no such syntax* in PowerShell - you'll have to use the default `.Item<n>` property (`Tuple`) / field (`ValueTuple`) names:

```
PS> ([ValueTuple]::Create(1, 'two')).Item2
two
```

However, PowerShell (Core) 7+ (*not* Windows PowerShell) offers convenient *positional indexing*:

```
PS> ([ValueTuple]::Create(1, 'two'))[1] # same as [-1] (last element) in this case 
two
```

---

In general, note that PowerShell's array literals are `[object[]]`-typed, so it's easy to create a collection of objects of disparate type:

```
PS> $arr = 1, 'two'; $arr[1]
two
```

If you want *named* elements, you can use a *hashtable* literal (which constructs a  `System.Collections.Hashtable` with case-insensitive key lookup):

```
PS> $ht = @{ Id = 1; Name = 'two' }; $ht.Name
two
```

To create a "property-bag" ad-hoc *object*, use a `[pscustomobject]` "cast" (in reality, this is syntactic sugar for directly constructing an object of that type, i.e. a quasi-anonymous PowerShell-only object):

```
PS> $obj = [pscustomobject] @{ Id = 1; Name = 'two' }; $obj.Name
two
```

Note that all these options won't perform as well as `ValueTuple`, but performance isn't PowerShell's focus in general.

---

Therefore, from a *PowerShell* perspective the answer to:

> What's the point of the tuple?

is:

Not much:

- Using them for optimized *performance* is generally not worth it in a *scripting* language such as PowerShell.
- Unlike in C#, there is *no syntactic sugar* for creating them, so explicit `[ValueTuple]::Create(...)` calls are always required, which are cumbersome.
- PowerShell's array literals and hashtable literals, for indexed / named mixed-type data structures, as shown above - are convenient, PowerShell-idiomatic alternatives. Native PowerShell command do not use tuples (though you may need to use them for calling .NET APIs directly).

  - As an aside: The `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2 }` syntactic sugar for creating the PowerShell analog of anonymous types in C# isn't as concise as one would hope (compare to C#: `new { foo = 1, bar = 2 }`).

Comment: Thanks. Add pls about №1 and №3 in my question. That's really interesting.

Comment: @Danny, Marc Gravell's answer already has that covered in general - I don't think there's anything PowerShell-specific to add there.

Comment: ok. May be someone else wants to add smoething later. But somebody has closed this question. "This question needs to be more focused" - my question is strongly focused on Tuples. How to fix this problem, and report about person who did this?

Comment: @Danny, I agree that the question is focused enough, and I've voted to reopen it. If others do the same, it will get reopened (not sure on the exact logic - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). There are ultimately no hard and fast rules with respect to question closures, but if the question ends up not being reopened and you'd like to start a conversation about that, you can do so at [meta].

Comment: @Danny, I've added a PowerShell-focused answer to your question #1 to the bottom of the answer.